# failed to execute 'send' on xmlhttprequest

Tags: ajax, web-services, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-ajax

After Number of hits on application, I m  getting error "failed to execute 'send' on Xmlhttprequest" on chrome browser and "operation has timed out " in application log .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640140/domexception-failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest-on-chrome-only

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issue to me. You'll need to set your headers on your SERVER side code to accept your application requests:

`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin:", "origin url of your site";
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST,PUT"`

Full docs about CORS headers here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin