# Make a synchronous redirectable CORS request in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cors, synchronous

Consider three domains: A, B and C. A piece of JavaScript code on domain A makes a standard **synchronous** `XMLHttpRequest` `GET` call to domain B, with only a `Accept` header, apart from the default ones. Domain B then redirects to domain C. Both responses (B and C) have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `*`. This works fine in Firefox and, as I have heard, in Internet Explorer too. However, Chrome doesn't seem to allow this. Asynchronous code, however, does work, also in Chrome.

Both synchronous and asynchronous requests directly to domain C (and the hypothetical domain D with the same properties) *do* work.

#### Related things that don't actually help AFAICT

Some quick things I explained above, to make it easier for dupe-hammer-wielders to read:

- ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20035101/5095300)
  It is.
- *It's just that Chrome doesn't allow synchronous CORS requests.*
  Non-redirected ones are allowed, as evident.
- [DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' on Chrome only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38640140/5095300)
  Indeed, this pointed me to the fact that it does work in other browsers, but saying that Firefox and IE "don't follow the jQuery specification" doesn't really help. On top of that, my question isn't about jQuery specifically. Also see the above note: direct requests do work.

Other things:

- *The request requires a preflight, which fails for other reasons.*
  My request is [simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests), so it shouldn't trigger a CORS preflight. Method: `GET`; Headers: `Accept`; <strike>no specified `Content-Type`</strike> EDIT: for simple requests, [Content-Type needs to be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928938/5095300), it seems. I fixed the code example accordingly.
- *The code triggers a CORS preflight anyway, because [the `Accept` value is non-standard](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165178)*
  That's currently not for Chrome.
- *Chrome made it more difficult to use sync. `XHR`s, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs).*
  Nope, that just restricts another feature I don't use.
- **I don't control either domain B or C**
- **The redirect from domain B to C is necessary**

#### Code to test

The following code makes a series of requests, first synchronously to domain B (which redirects to C), then async, then sync directly to domain C and async to C, and logs the results. Note that the log will probably not be in that order, because that's basically the point of asynchronism. Also note that, in this case, domain B *doesn't* have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, but I have tested this code on a domain B that does too (localhost, so not available here).

```js
function request(url, callback) {
  var synchronous = typeof callback !== 'function'
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  if (!synchronous) {
    xhr.onload = callback
  }
  xhr.open('GET', url, !synchronous)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.citationstyles.csl+json')
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  xhr.send(null)
  return xhr
}

var previewLength = 100

function handle(passed, message, data) {
  var item = document.createElement('li')
  item.innerText = message + (passed ? ' passed: ' : ' failed: ') + data
  var list = passed ? p : f
  list.appendChild(item)
}

var doi = '10.1093/BIOINFORMATICS/BTT178'
var domainB = 'doi.org'
var domainC = 'data.crossref.org'

var urlRedirect = '//' + domainB + '/' + doi
var urlDirect = '//' + domainC + '/' + doi

// sync domain B->C request
try {
  var response = request(urlRedirect)
  handle(true, 'sync domain B->C', response.responseText.slice(0, previewLength) + '...')
} catch (e) {
  handle(false, 'sync domain B->C', e)
}

// async domain B->C request
request(urlRedirect, function() {
  if (this.responseText[0] === '{') {
    handle(true, 'async domain B->C', this.responseText.slice(0, previewLength) + '...')
  } else {
    handle(false, 'async domain B->C')
  }
})

// sync domain C request
try {
  var response = request(urlDirect)
  handle(true, 'sync domain C', response.responseText.slice(0, previewLength) + '...')
} catch (e) {
  handle(false, 'sync domain C', e)
}

// async domain C request
request(urlDirect, function() {
  if (this.responseText[0] === '{') {
    handle(true, 'async domain C', this.responseText.slice(0, previewLength) + '...')
  } else {
    handle(false, 'async domain C')
  }
})
```

```html
Passed:
<ul id=p></ul>Failed:
<ul id=f></ul>
```

#### My question

- Are there any docs on why and when Chrome does this?
- Is there a workaround (i.e. for synchronous redirected CORS requests)? I know you can't block redirection in `XMLHttpRequest`, but perhaps there's another way.

I'm running Chromium 57.0.2987.98 32-bit.

Comment: I think it's just that synchronous calls have recently been deprecated and removed from Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's working as expected from Chrome 69 and onward, not sure how and why.